# V-for not working when building array from external JSON file

Tags: arrays, json, list, vue.js, v-for

Javascript:

```
// List of Products
const productsJSON = 'json/products.json';

// Component - Product Select
  app.component('product-select', {
    data() {
      return {
        selected: '',
        options: []
      }
    },
    template: `
      <p v-for="(option, index) in options">test</p>
      <div class="ui fluid labeled multiple search selection dropdown">
        <input type="hidden"
               name="products"
               v-model="selected"
               @change="selectProducts">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">Select Products</div>

        <div class="menu">
          <div v-for="(option, index) in options"
               class="item"
               v-bind:data-value="option.name">
            {{ option.name }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `,
    methods: {
      selectProducts(event) {
        this.selected = event.target.value.split(',');
        console.log(this.selected);
      }
    },
    beforeMount() {
      const jsonResults = [];
      this.options = jsonResults;

      $.getJSON(productsJSON, function (data) {
        jsonResults.push(...data);
      });
      console.log(jsonResults);
      console.log(this.options)
    }
  });
```

I'm simply trying to populate the `options: []` array with the array of objects returned from the JSON file in the `$.getJSON` function.  Here is what the JSON file looks like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "White Gummy",
    "value": "White Gummy"
  },
  {
    "name": "Red Gummy",
    "value": "Red Gummy"
  },
  {
    "name": "Blue Gummy",
    "value": "Blue Gummy"
  }
]
```

My `v-for` is returning absolutely nothing, and the results of my two `console.log` functions are as follows:

[image: console log]

Does anyone have any idea on what I'm doing wrong or if there is a better way to populate my array with the external .json file?

Comment: You assign jsonResults to this.options when jsonResults is empty. You should do that after getting the actual data from file I guess.

Comment: @Luckyfella and that's how I know I've been looking at this too long.  I made the change and that looks better, but the `v-for` is still empty like the array is being populated after the component is rendered even though it's all in `beforeMount()`

Comment: This post could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770681/javascript-vue-js-receive-json

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thank you @Luckyfella

Comment: use [vue.js devtools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) that would tell exactly what is in your component's data. if you for some reason don't want to use it you can check in template if your array has any elements in it by adding an HTML element any where in your template ```<div>{{ options.length }}</div>``` and i noticed you didn't assign a key for the loop

Answer (score 0):

@Luckyfella provided a solution, which can be found in the `created()` lifecycle hook below:

```
// Component - Product Select
  app.component('product-select', {
    data() {
      return {
        selected: '',
        options: null
      }
    },
    template: `
      <div class="ui fluid labeled multiple search selection dropdown">
        <input type="hidden"
               name="products"
               v-model="selected"
               @change="selectProducts">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">Select Products</div>

        <div class="menu">
          <div v-for="(option, index) in options"
               class="item"
               v-bind:data-value="option.name">
            {{ option.name }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `,
    methods: {
      selectProducts(event) {
        this.selected = event.target.value.split(',');
        console.log(this.selected);
      }
    },
    created: function () {
      fetch(productsJSON)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(options => {
          this.options = options;
        });
    }
  });
```